# JSF Managed bean clear fields in page after close

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

Here's the problem, I have a page with form and some fields. After filling up the fields and then saving the record, I then close the page. When I access the page again, the values in the fields still remain. I am expecting that the fields should be cleared once I closed the page, but it does not. I wonder why it happens. I tried using different scopes already but with no luck.

Comment: `RequestScoped` should do the trick.

Comment: Code. Code. Code. Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

Re initialize your `managed bean` just after saving it to database.
**or**
At the time when you are fetching the form related grid